# How do I get my GPS working on iPhone 3GS after upgrading to iOS 5?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone

I've upgraded my iPhone 3GS to iOS 5 and hence changed my baseband to 5.16.05. Now it is not possible for me to unlock the phone. Is there any way I could get both GPS and phone working?. I've done jailbreak with redsnow. I don't need iOS 5 and is willing to downgrade without breaking anything. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Why doesn't your GPS work?  I upgraded my iPhone 3GS and GPS works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now it is possible to **down**-grade your baseband - at least for the iPhone 3G and 3GS (unfortunately not 4/S) - from the iPad's 06.15 to 05.13.04 (un-lockable) thanks to the great work of the iPhone Dev Team:

> The iPhone Dev Team is happy to announce a baseband downgrade option in redsn0w for those who are using the iPad’s 06.15 baseband on the iPhone3G or iPhone3GS.
>
> Typically you’d have the 06.15 baseband if you unlock with ultrasn0w but updated your iPhone baseband past 05.13.04.  With this new capability, you can now downgrade specifically from 06.15 to 05.13.04 (even if you never had 05.13.04 on that device before).  This gives you the best of both worlds: ultrasn0w compatibility and a normal iPhone baseband with full GPS and the ability to use stock IPSWs again.

See [this post](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/26534086824/baseband-freedom) on their blog.

Comment: Does this restore GPS by just doing the downgrade?

Comment: @bmike: Yes it should restore GPS and push-notifications - as it's a fully functional iPhone baseband (and unlockable)

Answer (score 1):

No. You are out of luck.

Even if you had saved the SHSH blobs for iOS 4.X (which are what you'll require to rollback), you can't revert the baseband, which is required for the unlock. So even if you did manage to install iOS 4.X, you'd still be running baseband 5.16.05.

Comment: Is there any way to make the phone work again, without switching to ipad band?. Will there be any unlocker for this band, to be out soon?